# Kafka Consumer Error - Could not find attribute records-lag

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect my application to Kafka and I am able to do that successfully.
However, when I look at the logs, I get the below exception :

```
    WARN  2021-01-18 21:45:11,438 [**] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter [RequestID=] Error getting JMX attribute 'records-lag'
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: Could not find attribute records-lag
        at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter$KafkaMbean.getAttribute(JmxReporter.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter$KafkaMbean.getAttributes(JmxReporter.java:200)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttributes(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:709)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttributes(JmxMBeanServer.java:705)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanServerProxy$MBeanGetAttributesExecutor.execute(MBeanServerProxy.java:183)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanServerProxy$MBeanExecutionStrategy.execute(MBeanServerProxy.java:233)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanServerProxy.executeMBeanMethod(MBeanServerProxy.java:93)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanServerProxy.getAttributeList(MBeanServerProxy.java:74)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanReference.getAttributes(MBeanReference.java:59)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanAttributeReader.read(MBeanAttributeReader.java:86)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanSubscriptionManager.performMeasurements(MBeanSubscriptionManager.java:218)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.jmx.MBeanTracker.performMeasurements(MBeanTracker.java:63)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.MetricsProvider.captureJMX(MetricsProvider.java:220)
        at com.compuware.apm.agent.measures.MetricsProvider.capture(MetricsProvider.java:172)
```

This error is getting printed repeatedly. I tried different configurations but failed to resolve this.
Is there a way I can fix it ?

Comment: Hello, what configurations have you tried and please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is result of internal call to create mBeans for related JMX metrices.
[Refer link](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@kafka.apache.org/msg115677.html)  to get details

When collecting bulk metrics, this warning message in logs is unhelpful, it is
impossible to determine which MBean is missing this attribute and fix the
metric