# Spring Kafka consumer listener configuration

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My team and I are implementing Spring Kafka within our codebase, so to achieve all the benefits of an event-driven ecosystem.

The Spring Kafka configs are as follows:

```
...
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: >
        org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json.trusted.packages: "{trusted packages}"
          deserializer.value.delegate.class: >-
                  org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl:
        jaas:
          config: >
            ...
        mechanism: PLAIN
      basic:
        auth:
          ...
      schema:
        ...
      bootstrap:
        ...
  ...

app:
  kafka:
    event-type-one:
      topic: >-
        {topic}
      consumer-group-id: {group id}
      default-type: {default type event}
    event-type-two:
      topic: >-
        {topic}
```

And the Kafka Consumer is configured likewise:

```
    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["\${app.kafka.path.topic}"],
        groupId = "\${app.kafka.path.group-id}",
        properties = ["spring.json.value.default.type=\${app.kafka.event-type-one.default-type}"]
    )
    fun fooBar(record: ConsumerRecord<String, Any>) = runBlocking {
```

Please notice that we've provided a *default type* for our Consumer, because we are not specifying any headers in the incoming events, as per the docs [1].

The question is: when having a Spring Kafka configuration that enables the use of a Kafka Consumer, is providing a *default type* the correct approach in order to solve the "no headers provided" deserialisation error upon the Consumer trying to deserialise an event?
The *default type* is needed to be provided, according to the docs [1], if no headers are present in the event that's being produced and consumed via our *@KafkaListener* config.

Is this ***the right way*** to implement a Kafka Listener via the Spring Kafka [2] library?

Our goal is to potentially have more Consumers, so would that mean that for each Consumer (as it would have it's own event type) we need to provide a *default type*?

[1] https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-json-config

[2] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method signature is like that `record: ConsumerRecord<String, Any>` and you really cannot set a proper expected type via that parameter, then really only the way is to set that `spring.json.value.default.type` property. You also may need to look into a `spring.json.use.type.headers` property to be set to `false`. This way the `JsonDeserializer` won't look into headers for type at all, and will fallback to that provided default type. Do you have any problem with that kind of configuration?

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem, your input is much appreciated. I will follow your advices and post in this thread about the progress/questions/outcomes. The only question for now is: would setting a proper/fixed/final expected type via the parameter (instead of Any) be the better way?

Comment: I've given a try with having a concrete parameter instead of Any, and I've also provided the spring.json.use.type.headers set to false in application.yaml. It works as expected when testing. And it's an advantage I think to have the listener function accepting only 1 type of event object. Would we still need to have the spring.json.use.type.headers set to false in the configs though, given that we've provided a concrete parameter? AFAIK we'd want to prevent the Kafka listener looking for headers in any case (given that we don't expect any headers) - is that right?

Comment: Yeah... You don't need that property in case of concrete expected type in the function signature. The default one is `private volatile TypePrecedence typePrecedence = TypePrecedence.INFERRED;`. So, you can just disable type headers population from your producer side.

Comment: Ah, ok, so spring.json.use.type.headers is to be configured on the producer side of things? The other service that would produce to the topic that our service would consume should configure this spring.json.use.type.headers set to false?

Comment: No, on producer side that is a `spring.json.add.type.headers` property.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Artem. I'm struggling to understand, because when I don't provide a default type for my Kafka Listener, and I have a concrete parameter event in the signature, and I set json.use.type.headers: false -> I get "No type information in headers and no default type provided" when producing to the topic that that consumer is listening to. I am producing via the kafka-console-producer package from the Confluent community tools [1] and my understanding is that I shouldn't get this error. [1] https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html

Comment: Yeah... My bad: the deserializer works far before the listener method is called. So, you definitely need that `spring.json.value.default.type` property or try to use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and rely on a `JsonMessageConverter` which indeed looks into the listener method signature.

Comment: Thanks for your help Artem. I've marked your answer as the solution. One more thing, please, do you have some open source examples of your latest described approaches above?

Comment: This are samples we have so far: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples. That converter is explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

Comment: Hi Artem, can you please advice on how to solve the following warning log that keeps repeating itself a lot in our logs (when deploying the app): "o.a.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter : Error getting JMX attribute 'records-lag'". The references have not been of any help unfortunately: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12239 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795682/kafka-consumer-error-could-not-find-attribute-records-lag - any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, no. That one is out of Spring scope and better to ask for a help from Apache Kafka community. I only can suggest to add this `auto.include.jmx.reporter=true` into your Kafka config to disable this JMX stuff altogether.

Comment: Thanks Artem, that's very useful to know. Sorry, but did you mean to 
actually set it to 'false'? Like so: auto.include.jmx.reporter=false

Comment: Hi Artem, one more thing, please. At what tree level of the Kafka config (in application.yaml) this config needs to be placed? I assume if I include it under spring.kafka it's gonna work as expected and disable the JmxReporter for the whole app?

Comment: See in Spring Boot docs how to add Kafka generic property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Comment: Thanks Artem. I've added the config at: spring: kafka: properties: auto.include.jmx.reporter: false - but the JmxReporter errors have still been flooding our logs after the new deploy. I'll try to add this config for every Kafka component and see if that makes a difference.